# Sandwich/Squeeze Theorem Problem

Tags: calculus

the following problem is in regards to finding the limit using the squeeze theorem:

$$(3^{n}+1)^{1/n}$$

I feel fairly okay with the squeeze theorem in general, however, I seem to have a little bit of trouble finding the upper bounds of functions not involving trigonometric functions.

The lower bound seems a bit easier but I'm kind of unsure, do I just need to substitute $n=1$ as the lowest possible value?

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Here's a great application of the squeeze theorem:    URL = {https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2843059  The bounds are upper and lower Riemann sums with just $1$  subinterval...

Comment: Using Bernoulli's Inequality, we have

$$3\le (3^n+1)^{1/n}\le 3\left(1+\frac1{n3^n}\right)$$

Applying the squeeze theorem, yields the coveted result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$3=(3^{n})^{1/n} < (3^{n}+1)^{1/n}<(3^{n}+3^{n})^{1/n}=(2(3^{n}))^{1/n}=2^{1/n}3$ and $2^{1/n} \to 1$.

Comment: Okay yes that makes sense, however i'm just slightly confused (this might seem stupid), why did you pick that as the upper bound? Also I thought the squeeze theorem was specifically used for functions that are Greater/Less than or **equal** to?

Comment: I just thought of an upper bound that makes calculations simple.

Answer (score 1):

Simply noting the inequality 
$$3^n < 3^n + 1 < 2 \times 3^n$$
and the fact $\lim_{n \to \infty} 2^{1/n} = 1$.