# How to derive $e^x = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( 1 + \frac x n \right)^ n$ directly from $e = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^ n$?

Tags: exponentiation

If given the definition of $ e $:

$$e = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^ n$$

Using this fact alone, can it directly derive

$$e^x = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{x}{n}\right)^n$$

for positive and negative integer $x$ and in general, for any real number $x$?

Comment: Observing $\left(1 + \frac{x}{n}\right)^n = \left(\left(1 + \frac{1}{n/x}\right)^{n/x}\right)^x$ will handle some cases, but there is more work to be done (e.g., dealing with negative $x$, verifying that $e = \lim_{y \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{y}\right)^y$ when the limit is taken over the reals and not just the integers, etc.).

Comment: What is your definition of $e^x$?

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2842995/is-there-a-way-to-show-that-ex-lim-n-to-infty-left1-fracxn-rightn) is the same.

Comment: mine is to directly derive it from $e = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^ n$

Comment: @angryavian do we have to prove separately for integer $x$ and real $x$?

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to directly derive it:

$$
\begin{align} 
\text{since} \ e & = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^ n  \\\\
e^x & = \left(\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^ n\right)^x \\
& = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^ {nx} \\\\
\text{ let } m & = nx \ \ \text{ where } x \gt 0 \\\\
\text{ so } n & = \frac m x \\\\
e^x & = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{\frac m x}\right)^ {m} \\
& = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac x m\right)^ {m} \\
& = \lim_{m \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac x m\right)^ {m}  \ \ \text {since  $m \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$}  \\ \\ 
\text{re-writting the above}\\
 e^x & = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{x}{n}\right)^ n  \\\\
\text{It is easy to see the above holds} & \text { for $x = 0$, so}\\\\
 e^x & = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{x}{n}\right)^ n \ \ \  \forall x \ge 0  \\\\
\text {Now let} \ y & = -x \ \ \ \text where \ x \ge 0\\\\
e^y &= e^{-x}\\
&= \frac 1 {e^x}\\
&= \frac {1} {\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{x}{n}\right)^ n}\\
&= \frac {1} {\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac n n + \frac{x}{n}\right)^ n}\\
&= \frac {1} {\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{n + x}{n}\right)^ n}\\
&= {\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac n {n + x}\right)^ n}\\
\\
\text{ let } m &= n + x \text {, so the above}\\
e^y &= {\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac {m - x} {m}\right)^ {m-x}}\\
&= {\lim_{m \to \infty} \left(\frac {m - x} {m}\right)^ {m-x}} \ \ \text {since $m \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$} \\
&= {\lim_{m \to \infty} \left(1 - \frac {x} {m}\right)^ {m-x}}\\
&= {\lim_{m \to \infty} \frac{ \left(1 - \frac {x} {m}\right)^ {m}}{ \left(1 - \frac {x} {m}\right)^ {x}}}\\
\text{ Since } {\lim_{m \to \infty} \left(1 - \frac {x} {m}\right)^ {x}} \ \ & \text {is just} \ 1 \  \text{for finite} \  x \text {, so} \ \\\
e^y &= {\lim_{m \to \infty} \left(1 - \frac {x} {m}\right)^ {m}}\\
&= {\lim_{m \to \infty} \left(1 - \frac {(-y)} {m}\right)^ {m}}\\
&= {\lim_{m \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac {y} {m}\right)^ {m}} \ \ \  \forall y = -x \le 0 \\ \\
\text {Therefore, combining the case for } \ & x \ge 0 \ \text {and $y \lt 0$, }\\\\
e^x &= {\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac {x} {n}\right)^ {n}} \ \ \ \forall x \in \Bbb R \\
\end{align}$$